# In R: Create data.frame objects inside a cycle for with multiple indices

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, cycle, assign

I'm stuck with my code. 
I have a dataset (ds) with N rows. 
My goal is to filter out from my dataset a set of rows, where the number of rows to filter out depends on 2 parameters.

What I did is a cycle for different values of i  (i= 1, .., I; the first parameter) and different values of j (j = 1, ..,J; the second parameter). The content inside the cycle aims to drop selected rows and create a reduced version of the dataset (that I call ds2).

So, for each i-j combination, I want to store K = I*J ds2 reduced datasets objects as data.frame. 
The point is: the cycle works with indices "i" and "j", but then I want to store object using the index "k".

I attach my code, where I set i = 2:3 and j = 9:10 (so, K = 4). 
I use temp + assign to create my dataset objects.

This code succeed in creating 4 data.frame objects, but it fails in creating them correctly, since all of them are equal (they are all referring to one of the 4 combinations)

```
ds2 = paste("ds2_",c(seq(1,4,1)),sep="") # i then assign each dataset to one of the elements in ds2 

for (k  in 1:length(ds2)){   # datasets to generate
for (i in seq(2,3, by = 1)){ # parameter i values
    for (j in seq(9,10, by = 1)) { # parameter j values

        ds$active = 1   # once the first loop ends, I reset the variable active to 1

        v_1mm = rollapply(ds$v_1, i , max)
        v_2mm = rollapply(ds$v_2, i , max)
        v_3mm = rollapply(ds$v_3, i , max)
        v_4mm = rollapply(ds$v_4, i , max)
        v_5mm = rollapply(ds$v_5, i , max)
        v_6mm = rollapply(ds$v_6, i , max)
        v_7mm = rollapply(ds$v_7, i , max)
        v_8mm = rollapply(ds$v_8, i , max)
        v_9mm = rollapply(ds$v_9, i , max)
        v_10mm = rollapply(ds$v_10, i , max)

        ds$v_1mm = c(rep(0, i-1), v_1mm)
        ds$v_2mm = c(rep(0, i-1), v_2mm)
        ds$v_3mm = c(rep(0, i-1), v_3mm)
        ds$v_4mm = c(rep(0, i-1), v_4mm)
        ds$v_5mm = c(rep(0, i-1), v_5mm)
        ds$v_6mm = c(rep(0, i-1), v_6mm)
        ds$v_7mm = c(rep(0, i-1), v_7mm)
        ds$v_8mm = c(rep(0, i-1), v_8mm)
        ds$v_9mm = c(rep(0, i-1), v_9mm)
        ds$v_10mm = c(rep(0, i-1), v_10mm)

        ds$active[(ds$v_1mm <= j | is.na(ds$v_1)) & 
        (ds$v_2mm <=j | is.na(ds$v_2)) & 
        (ds$v_3mm <=j | is.na(ds$v_3)) & 
        (ds$v_4mm <=j | is.na(ds$v_4)) & 
        (ds$v_5mm <=j | is.na(ds$v_5)) & 
        (ds$v_6mm <=j | is.na(ds$v_6)) & 
        (ds$v_7mm <=j | is.na(ds$v_7)) & 
        (ds$v_8mm <=j | is.na(ds$v_8)) & 
        (ds$v_9mm <=j | is.na(ds$v_9)) & 
        (ds$v_10mm <=j | is.na(ds$v_10))] = 0

        temp = ds[ds$active==1,] # temporary object
        assign(ds2[k], temp) # assign the object to ds2 
        }
}
```

Is there a correct way to create a data.frame object for each loop of the cycle? It make sense or not to set a third cycle in k?

Thanks in advance

Rodolfo

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your dataset `ds`

Comment: Dear Chriss, here you are a row of ds, v_1, .., v_10  are the velocity of basketball players. I have some NA, because there are 5 players each time on the court in a specific moment.                                                                                                      
                                                                                                             
        action_id ms         v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4 v_5 v_6 v_7 v_8 v_9 v_10
        1            35564000 1.78 0.51 1.92 NA NA   0.07 0.76 NA NA NA